# Linq query where contains List in a List

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to query MongoDB to get Top 5000 Records, which results in following error.
I am using C# LINQ Driver, and TermMonitorIds is a BsonArray.

**{"Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression: x.ToString()."}**

```
public IList<SocialRecord> GetManyBetweenDatesLimited(List<string> termMonitorIds, string[] sources, DateTime fr, DateTime to)
        {
            IList<SocialRecord> entities = new List<SocialRecord>();

            try
            {
                entities =
                    (from e in this.collection.AsQueryable<SocialRecord>()
                     where (e.TermMonitorIds.Any(x => termMonitorIds.Contains(x.ToString()))) && (sources.Contains(e.SocialType))
                                                             && (e.DateCreated.Date >= fr.Date) && (e.DateCreated.Date <= to.Date)
                     select e)
                    .Take(5000)
                    .ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error("Error Message", ex);
            }

            return entities;
        }
```

I tried changing List to BsonArray like below:

```
BsonArray bArray = new BsonArray();
            foreach (var term in termMonitorIds )
            {
                bArray.Add(term.ToBson());
            }
```

Still end up wit an error message like:

Server Error in '/' Application.

A String value cannot be written to the root level of a BSON document.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: A String value cannot be written to the root level of a BSON document.

Comment: What version of MongoDB do you use?

Comment: MongoDb 2.4.9 version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LINQ provider doesn't support `ToString` because it it wouldn't know how to translate it as an MongoDB expression.

I'd suggest you update `termMonitorIds` to match the expected data-type returned by `e.TermMonitorIds` e.g. `List<int>` / `List<Guid>`, avoiding the need for any sort of conversion (it's generally more efficient without it).

Comment: LINQ to SQL? I don't think so :-)

Comment: @sloth yeah realised what I had written *after* I had written it haha